# Elasticsearch, how to do a must_not with a nested_field in the filter context of aggregation section?

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, aggregation

In my index, I have the following documents

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "_source" : {
      "in_stock" : false,
      "warehouses" : 
      [
            {
              "warehouse" : "AC",
               "city" : "NY"

            },
            {
              "warehouse" : "AD"
               "city" : "MS"
            }
        ]
    }
}
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "_source" : {
      "in_stock" : false,
      "warehouses" : 
      [
            {
              "warehouse" : "**",
               "city" : "NY"

            },
            {
              "warehouse" : "AD"
               "city" : "MS"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I would like to aggregate in that way :

```
"agg-mystock": {
  "nested": {
    "path": "warehouses"
  },
  "aggs": {
    "agg_by_value": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [{
            "nested": {
              "path": "warehouses",
              "query": {
                "match": { "warehouses.warehouse": "**" }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "nested": {
              "path": "warehouses",
              "query": {
                "match": { "warehouses.warehouse": "AA"}
              }
            }
          }]
        }
        }
      },
      "top_reverse_nested": {
        "reverse_nested": {}
      }
    }
},
```

It seems the filter context with must_not does not work. So my question is : how to make to work in the aggs section ? Is there any equivalent to the must_not in the filter context for aggregations parts ?
I have tried some scripts, but it does not work

Thanks